# Jenkins_Selenium- Can someone please explain how to generate reports in jenkins and send it as attachement in email

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

Jenkins_Selenium- Can some one please explain how to generate reports in jenkins and send it as attachement in email. I tried SelenuimHTML report plugin and added it as post build action. In selenium results location i have given as testng-results. Is this correct?

Thanks,
Deepa

Comment: I get the following error after running the tests
"Publishing Selenium report...
Missing directory testng-results
Build step 'Publish Selenium Html Report' marked build as failure"

Answer (score 0):

Just use TestNG as your test-runner.  I will generate a "emailable report" HTML file, then you can use Jenkins EmailExt plugin to send with the attachment.   If you want a more detailed report, some people use the Maven plugin called ReportNG  to generate a emailable report but personally I don't think its any better.

Comment: Yeah we get an emailable report when we run as testng in eclipse, but in my case i am not running from eclipse. I am running in jenkins where the code is pulled from github. Git hub does not dispaly any reports. The Report files will be in HTMl code format.

Comment: When you run on jenkins, you need to run your TestNG project using the maven-surefire plugin, which has an option to point to a testng.xml file of your choice.  THen, when its done, your HTML output will be stored by Surefire (after executing TestNG) under the workspace/target directory.